# React Router doesnt work when I try to render the components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try to render the components with React Router, but it doesnt seem to work. I can't find what I do wrong after the changes on React router.
I don't get any errors. The components are just not rendering on the page.
I tried add BrowserRouter too, nothing changes.

My code

```
import './default.scss'
import { Routes ,Route  } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainLayout from './layouts/MainLayout';

import Homepage from './pages/Homepage';
import Registration from './pages/Homepage/Registration';

function App() {
  return (
    
      <Routes>
         <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
           <MainLayout>
             <Homepage/>
           </MainLayout>
         )}
          ></Route>
         <Route path="/registration" render={() => (
           <MainLayout>
             <Registration/>
           </MainLayout>
         )}
          ></Route>
         </Routes>
         
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm confused, why do you have two routes both going to the path /?

Comment: the path for both routes are same.. change that accordingly.. path="/" for homepage, path="/registration" for registration .. and which version are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, my code was wrong after I tried changing it so many times, even when the paths are diffrent the result is the same. I changed the code now to what was in the begining the problem. I'm using the v6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess your using `react-route-dom` v6, you can check out the guide [upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

Change route following

```js
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <MainLayout>
        <Homepage/>
      </MainLayout>
    }
  />
  <Route
    path="registration"
    element={
      <MainLayout>
        <Registration/>
      </MainLayout>
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

or using [useRoutes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-useroutes-instead-of-react-router-config)

```js
let element = useRoutes([
  // These are the same as the props you provide to <Route>
  {
    path: "/",
    element:
      <MainLayout>
        <Homepage/>
      </MainLayout> },
  {
    path: "registration",
    element:
      <MainLayout>
        <Registration/>
      </MainLayout>
  },
  // Not found routes work as you'd expect
  { path: "*", element: <NotFound /> },
]);
```

Comment: Thank you! That works for me. I was not using the element. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the BrowserRouter??

Which error is throwing the code?

Comment: The code is not throwing any errors.  My components are just not rendering on the page. I tried with BrowserRouter too. Its the same

Comment: add this as comment but not as answer